# Win32_PhysicalMemory.Capactiy -- How does it behave in 32-bit applications?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, operating-system, wmi

The way I understand Win32_PhysicalMemory.Capacity in the WMI is that if you add up all the different rows it has, it'll total up to how much RAM is actually usable for Windows.

However, what about things like 32-bit machines that have more than 2G of memory (via Physical Address Extensions)? If there was 6G of actual usable memory, would it return that, or would it return 2G or 4G?

Comment: Use 64-bit math when adding.  Also see related discussion http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/32da73c1-de42-4c74-b59e-4f1e51d2e7a2  I don't think the value you're inspecting returns only usable memory.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the properties values of the [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class are inherited from [`CIM_PhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), In this case the `Capacity` property value comes from the the [SMBIOS 2.7.1](http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf) Memory Device table (Type 17). So answering your question the value returned by this property is **the size of the memory device**.